# Debian send ip address on startup (sheevaplug)

Tags: linux, email, startup

I'm having a sheevaplug with debian (default) installed on it.

I would like to receive a mail with the ip-address of the sheevaplug, everytime it is restarted, AND everytime the ip address changes.

I have no idea how to do this...

I realize I'm asking multiple things at once, so part of the solution is also ok:

- how to write something that runs on startup?
- how to send a mail?
- how to detect a change in ip address?
- how to retrieve the correct ip address? (ifconfig gives a lot of information I don't need)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dyndns (see @taspeotis' answer) is not what you want, you can:

- run commands once a network interface comes up by using the post-up hook of ifup (see man interfaces(8)
- send email: `echo "mail body" | mail -s subject recipient@foo.bar`
- detect changes of ip-address: this will probably happen if you use dhcp, if you're using dhclient you could use its `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient-enter-hooks.d`
- get the correct ip address: `ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr"`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to know the IP address of the box so you can access it remotely? You may be better off with a DynDNS domain and client: http://www.dyndns.com/support/clients/#linux

Comment: Not exactly what I want, but maybe I customise the ddclient a bit to do what I need... I will check this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For retrieve actual ip and mail you can do:

```
$ ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr" | mail -s subject yourmail@gmail.com
```